# How to specify path in .config file relative path to folder?

Tags: deployment

I have folder "NuGetPackages". I need to access only the folder on my computer is OK but on server is different folder structure where the project is store
what i use on my computer absolute path:

> C:\workspace\HUD\02_Development\04_Tools\NuGetServer\NuGetPackages

What should I write in the config file to make sure the path is ..\NuGetPackages expanded relative to the config file rather the working?
 directory?

I can't change the app I can only change the config file.
I have also try "~/NuGetPackages" but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't do exactly what you're trying to do.

If you can't change any of the code, your only real option is to use config transforms. You can have your *.Debug.config use your local path, and then your *.Release.config (or whatever your published build configuration is), and use the server's path.

Here are some docs on doing config transforms: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx